# When working with non-normally distributed time series data, how can I determine when metric is significantly (@ 95% CI) lower/higher than historical?

Tags: time-series, distributions, statistical-significance

I'm working with time series data that looks at a conversion rate day by day. I have the data going back a few years. I'd like to build in some logic/alert/etc. so that I know when the conversion rate for a specific day is meaningfully lower/higher than what we've seen historically. When I say "meaningfully", I'm referring to a 95% tolerance interval.

My data isn't normally distributed (I've run a QQ plot & Shapiro test), and this is where I get stumped.

I'd appreciate any help anyone can provide - my stats knowledge is a bit rusty as of late :)

Comment: Two standard deviations, or two standard errors? Standard error is what we use to calculate the confidence interval. I think you might be looking for something more like a [tag:tolerance-interval].

Comment: I suppose 2 standard errors. I'm looking for 95% CI first & foremost, and I know in a normal distribution that equates to 2 standard deviations, but that wouldn't be in the case for a non-normally distributed data set.

Comment: You are mixing up standard deviation and standard error. Standard error depends on sample size. Would you require a smaller deviation from some baseline if you had twice as many observations?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding. I am looking for 95% tolerance intervals, not confidence intervals, and I will edit the question accordingly.